# VBA office 2016 windows7/10 difference: Set IXMLDOMNodeList = DOMDocument60.childNodes

Tags: vba, excel

I've got an issue with a piece of VBA code that runs fine on a windows 7 machine, but doesn't work on windows 10. My VBA skills aren't good enough to figure this one out.

This part of the code in run in a Excel class and is used to load a `xml` file and return the `xml` as a class.

```
Public Function GetDomNodeList(ByRef log As Logger) As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
Dim domdocument As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

'Open file for handling
domdocument.async = False
domdocument.Load (strThisFilePath)

'Call the helper sub to do the actual work:
Set GetDomNodeList = domdocument.childNodes
End Function
```

When debugging it tells me there is a type mismatch. I've tried to debug the issue, but I'm running short on knowledge here. My main question is why this works on windows 7 and why not on windows 10 running the same office version (2016) VBA7.1

Comment: 32 bit vs 64 bit versions of windows? This might cause a difference . Alternatively check version number of the XML parser

Comment: Good one. Didn't check. But both machines run 64bit of windows 7/10. Both Excel versions are 32bit and build version 16.0.8431.2270

Comment: The version number of the XML parser, do you mean the Microsoft XML, v6.0 or some other version information? Both machines use the same.

Comment: A type mismatch suggests that one of your "As" statements is no longer a valid type. If they both use the same version of MSXML2 then it must be Byref log As logger?

Comment: @Harassed dad Thing is the logger isn't the issue. The debugger stops on the line :
    Set GetDomNodeList = domdocument.childNodes
The part where the logger is used I've stripped out of the pasted code as the debugger didn't stumble on that part of the code. Only on the last line of the code it stops.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trials I found a solution. Export the class, remove it and import the class again and all magically works again. I'm baffled by this.

Comment: Excel compiles to p-code behind the scenes. If something goes wrong with that then forcing a recompile (which is what your process did effectively) is the only way of sorting it. I suspect that was the problem